# Address locator style for my database?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, address

I'm a student studying GIS, and I need to create geocoding for my work.

How can I create the address locator style for fields with my requirements and my specified shapefile.

My attributes are:

```
Id
Survey_No
Owner_Name
Cadestre_No
Soil_Type
Cult_Type
Water_Sour
Rights
Bebts
```

Comment: My recommendation is to start by reviewing [Defining the address locator components](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Defining_the_address_locator_components/002500000010000000/) and if that does not resolve it then edit your question to focus it on the specific place where that starts to confuse you.

Answer (score 2):

You will find information on customizing your own locator style in the Esri Geocoding Technical Paper: [*Customizing Locators in ArcGIS 10*](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=aeb00de638f3492a93308a4a03183c7d).